# ag-chart-tooltip is not displaying the tooltip - css not getting picked up by the app

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid

Im plotting a simple line chart inside my angular application using ag-charts . Though the chart is getting plotted I do not see the tool tip getting displayed, when I hover the mouse over the data point.

However I do tooltip content getting populated in the tool tip content (see screen shot ).

How do I debug this  to see what is blocking it from getting displayed?, I do not see any error on the chrome console though.

Update :
As pointed by @Osy4C , the root cause for this issue is the opacity getting set to 0 . Setting it to 1 on the browser does show the tool tip. However, the app does not pickup this from the css .

How should I get this work ?

[image]

I tried the following in the .css file for this component, neither of them works. It does not get picked up by the app and opacity gets set to '0' by default when the app loads.

```
ag-chart-tooltip {
  opacity: 1; 
}
.ag-chart-tooltip-visible { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: can you share your ts and html file ?

Comment: @Elmehdi, please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with some more reading I made the tooltip appear by setting the property "[encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)" in the component. like so :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-results-timeline',
  templateUrl: './results-timeline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results-timeline.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And the results-timeline.component.css file contains :

```
.ag-chart-tooltip  {
  opacity: 1 ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip opacity is 0 if it is not visible.

Put this in the css:

```
.ag-chart-tooltip-visible { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Please read my update on this post. I tried the following in the .css file for this component, neither of them works. It does not get picked up by the app and opacity gets set to '0' by default when the app loads.

.ag-chart-tooltip {
  opacity: 1; 
}
.ag-chart-tooltip-visible { opacity: 1; }